# Has anyone used the ConstraintRelationship class for Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc152119.aspx) there is a property on the AppointmentRequest class for the CRM webservice that allows you to add constraints to what possible appointments are returned from a search.

The actual constraint is specified as an xml string, but I can find almost no documentation about it. Can any one point me to any relevant resources?

Answer (score 3):

I was never able to find any quality documentation on this property or an accepted schema.  About all that is available (that I've found) exists on this example from the SDK: [Schedule A Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151190.aspx)

You can kind of see how you would limit the search results to a set of resources/users.  The list of which properties can be replaced for "name" in the example is in the article [ConstraintRelation.Constraints Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc152119.aspx).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Also, you might try looking through the CRM 3 SDK.  When I was looking for the error codes that can be returned for one of the scheduling messages... they were not in the CRM 4 SDK but WERE present in the CRM 3 SDK.  Go figure.